# SSH on boot via rc.local

Tags: boot, ssh, bash

I am trying to `ssh` into a server on boot. I have written a simple bash script to perform this action. The script works fine if I run it from the command line, issue is with `rc.local`.
The script `/home/RPi_1/autoCon.sh` is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 20

while true; do ssh tone4@192.168.xxx.xxx \
       -R 22:localhost:22 -N -o ServerAliveInterval=10; \
       sleep 5; done
```

`/etc/rc.local`:

```
/home/RPi_1/autoCon.sh > /home/RPi_1/autossh.log 2>&1 &
exit 0
```

The `autossh.log` file is filled with this error: Host key verification failed.

I have two users on the my Raspberry Pi, Pi and RPi_1. I think I have identified the issue being that when `rc.local` is being executed it is executed as root or Pi? Thus, when the key is being searched for it is looking in the wrong directory? The key for the server is in /home/RPi_1/.ssh/

Similar issue at: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=261103

3B running Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Comment: Please accept the answer of *Milliways* and create a new question to ask how to use **systemd** to run your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further expand on the question and the replies:

If you need to automate a startup script indeed `rc.local` is not the right way to do it. Not even a `cron`. A `systemd` service is preferable and you can set up **dependencies**. In your case the script should not start until networking is ready. Waiting for an arbitrary number of seconds is wasteful and does not guarantee that the network will be ready. Make the service run as your user `RPi_1` (or `pi` ?): [example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot).

I would also suggest to use [autossh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh). If the connection is interrupted for some reason, then your script will reconnect automatically. You `while` loop does more or less the same but there is a tool for that.

Answer (score 1):

`rc.local` is run as root.

This is only the start of your problems.

You should **NOT** use `rc.local` on `systemd` - there must be hundreds of posts on this site discussing the issue. I will not waste time on the problems with the script you are trying to run.

To make matters worse you are using an obsolete OS, which makes it even harder for anyone to help.